# Addition of 2D Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class project that is to make and operate on dynamic objects. 
I have a class called Matrix that uses a 2 dimensional pointer array to store object of type Complex (which is a complex number class). I need to be able to add 2 arrays by adding all of the values in the arrays together and returning a new array. The issue is that I don't understand the syntax for accessing each Complex object in the array. Here is what I have so far for the overloaded addition operator:

```
const Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const
{
    Matrix newMatrix(mRows,mCols); 
    for(int i=0;i<mRows;i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<mCols;j++) 
        {
            (*newMatrix.complexArray[i]) = (*complexArray[i])+    (*rhs.complexArray[i]);
        }   
    }

return newMatrix;
}
```

Here is the overloaded input operator for the Matrix object:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Matrix& matrix) 
{
bool inputCheck = false;
int cols;

while(inputCheck == false)
{
    cout << "Input Matrix: Enter # rows and # columns:" << endl; 

    input >> matrix.mRows >> cols;
    matrix.mCols = cols/2;

    //checking for invalid input
    if(matrix.mRows <= 0 || cols <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Input was invalid. Try using integers." << endl;
        inputCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        inputCheck = true;
    }

    input.clear();
    input.ignore(80, '\n');
}

if(inputCheck = true)
{
    cout << "Input the matrix:" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i< (matrix.mRows+matrix.mCols);i++) 
    {
        Complex* newComplex = new Complex();
        input >> *newComplex;
        matrix.complexArray[i] = newComplex;
    }
}
return input;
}
```

Here is the Matrix class definition:

```
class Matrix
{
friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Matrix&);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Matrix&);

private:
    int mRows;
    int mCols;
    static const int MAX_ROWS = 10;
    static const int MAX_COLUMNS = 15;

            Complex **complexArray;

public:

            Matrix(int=0,int=0);
            Matrix(Complex&);
            ~Matrix();
            Matrix(Matrix&);
            Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&);
            const Matrix operator+(const Matrix&) const;
};
```

And the constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c)
{
if(r>0 && c>0)
{
    mRows = r;
    mCols = c;
}
else
{
    mRows = 0;
    mCols = 0;
}

if(mRows < MAX_ROWS && mCols < MAX_COLUMNS)
{
    //complexArray= new Complex[mRows];
    complexArray= new Complex*[mRows];

    for(int i=0;i<mRows;i++)
    {
        complexArray[i] = new Complex[mCols];
    }
}
}
```

As it is now, the program compiles, but stops working when it gets to the addition of matrices during runtime. If anyone can tell me what syntax I should be using and why, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be taking in enough input. You're taking (rows+cols) complex numbers as input but then attempting (correctly) to iterate over (rows*cols) elements within the matrix.

```
for(int i=0;i< (matrix.mRows+matrix.mCols);i++)
```

versus

```
for(int i=0;i<mRows;i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<mCols;j++)
```